# about table expansion in regular relationships in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to understand the Microsoft power bi documentation about "Understand Model Relationships" ; I understood most part of the documentation, except **expanding table in regular relationships and limited relationships**. Below is the paragraph that I am referring to from the document:

"At query time, regular relationships permit table expansion to take place. Table expansion results in the creation of a virtual table by including the native columns of the base table and then expanding into related tables. For Import tables, it's done in the query engine; for DirectQuery tables it is done in the native query sent to the source database (as long as the Assume referential integrity property isn't enabled). The query engine then acts upon the expanded table, applying filters and grouping by the values in the expanded table columns."

The above mentioned paragraph is under the heading: "**Regular Relationships**". Would anyone please help me understand the context. Thank you for giving your valuable time.

[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-relationships-understand#relationship-evaluation)
Please find the link to the document in this post

Comment: Alberto Ferrari write a good article about this topic, where You can find an explanation

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/expanded-tables-in-dax/

Comment: Alberto, I read the information on the link you shared; got the needed understanding. I am yet to start to DAX calculations to have a complete understanding of the information; however, I got a (basic) doubt in the explanation. What does a base table refer to in the table expansion? Thank you, Alberto